# Image Closing when Moving Mouse

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a menu show up when you press a button. When you press the button, it appears. However, when I move my cursor, the menu disappears.

```py
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
    if self.ui.menuUI.get_rect(topright = (1850, 0)).collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
        self.ui.show_menu()
```

Here's the show_menu()

```py
def show_menu(self):
    self.display_surface.blit(self.menuUII,self.MenuUII_rect)
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

You must draw the image in the application loop. Set a state when the button is clicked. And draw the image depending on the state:

Constructor:

```py
self.show_ui = False
```

Event handling:

```py
# event loop
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        run = False    

    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
        if self.ui.menuUI.get_rect(topright = (1850, 0)).collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            self.show_ui = True
```

when drawing the scene

```py
if self.show_ui:
    self.ui.show_menu()
```

Comment: @Dr.Doofenshmirtz So you did it wrong. I cannot debug your code.